# Cast an Objective C UITextField value to float

Tags: objective-c, casting, uitextfield

I have a UITextField called txtDiscount
It has a value in it: txtDiscount.text == 2.3 //for example

I've tried:

```
float test = (NSNumber *)txtDiscount.text;
```

And it compiles, but at runtime breaks down.

> Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = ..."; desired type = NSNumber; given type = NSCFString; value = .

How can I cast the value?

Any help greatly appreciated,
Thanks // :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
float test = [txtDiscount.text floatValue];
```

The [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/floatValue) documentation provides a list of all the built-in casts.

Comment: I thought this had covered it, but I'm still getting a compilation error. Let me explain more. I have an attribute in a Core Data entity. It is declared there as type float. Core Data creates an interface to it: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * discount; and an implementation for it: @dynamic discount; I use that to access that attribute through a managed object context.

This works:

float test = [txtDiscount.text floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f", test); 

This breaks:

[product setDiscount:test];

The compilation error is: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setDiscount:'

Comment: Yes, because setDiscount needs an NSNumber, not a float. Sounds like you need to do: [product setDiscount:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[txtDiscount.text floatValue]]];

But, to be brutally honest, it sounds like you really need some programming courses. You do know you shouldn't be using floats (or doubles) to represent dollar amounts, right? I hope you're not doing that...

Comment: Yes, I know. Decimal, double, float: 3 decimal including choices in Core Data with MySQL as the persistent data store. What I know of MySQL data types says that decimal is a double stored as a string, allowing for a fixed decimal point. Hence it's bigger than float and slower. And it's not necessary if you are just setting values that aren't going to be used in calculations. Then again, I guess string works in that case too. Thanks though.

Comment: The answer is not correct. It works only for US floats (with the dot to separate the decimal part of the integer part) but `[txtDiscount.text floatValue]` does not work for french people with a "," as decimal separator.

Answer (score 2):

A cast like this

```
(NSNumber *)myInstance
```

is telling the compiler to treat 'myInstance' as if it were an instance of class NSNumber. This may influence compile time warnings and errors. Note: - the compiler. It makes no difference to the code that is generated or run - at all. The code that you are running is still

```
float test = [txtDiscount text];
```

where the method -text is returning a pointer to an NSString and you are trying to assign it to a float variable.

see clee's answer for how to get  float value from an NSString - but make sure you understand why what you were trying to do is wrong. It will help loads in the long run.

Comment: Totally agree, just wish I could see through the auto generated code fog I note in my comment to clee :)